# Can we merge the shapefile and shp tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There are 8 shp tags and it has no wiki. I think making the extension of shapefiles an alias makes sense.

Comment: [tag:shp] already is a synonym for [tag:shapefile].  (Notice that the links, which are based on "shp" and "shapefile", both go to the same page.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hint. One way to see if a tag has synonyms is:

Click on the tag [shp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shp), for example. You will see this:

[image]

The red circle shows there is one (1) synonym of shp. Click on "synonyms" to see all tags and which one is the master.

[image]

In the above screenshot we can see shp was made a synonym of [shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapefile) (the master tag).